# LOAD DATA into TABLE not inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import data from a CSV file to my table using PHP.  I have tried using the exact same code without the backslash for ENCLOSED BY '"' on phpmyadmin and the import is successful.

I have also checked the user permissions for admin.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'admin', 'admin');
$pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try{
$query = $pdo->prepare("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\feed.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE tablename

fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '\"'
lines terminated by '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES

(field1, field2, field3, field4)", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));

$query->execute();
$query->fetchAll();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

When running this code I am seeing this error:

```
General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

Comment: "It shows no errors" -- are you relying solely on the PDOException for errors, or have you turned on PHP's error reporting as well?

Comment: I have error_reporting(1); and the PDOException errors turned on, can you tell me what else I can use to view all errors?

Comment: Instead of `error_reporting(1)`, try 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: ok I can see the error - I have added PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY and $query->fetchAll(); after $query->execute(); and I still see the same error

Comment: Beneath your PDO setup, add `$pdo->closeCursor(); `

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::closeCursor() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\import_csv.php on line 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81564/discussion-between-kittykittybangbang-and-user3312792).

Answer (score 0):

I don't no what is wrong in your code but you can use my code it is help full to you I think

I have implement this code and it is tested code. I think it is very use full

You have follow some rule:-

1.your csv file according to database table name (ex: db table name is users then csv should be users.csv)

2.Your csv file's first row should be db table fields name (ex: Id, name etc) after the start your data entry

3.you can download data source class from :- http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/ because i have require below the code: require_once 'CSV/DataSource.php';

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "excel_import";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

$conn=mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("I cannot connect to the database because: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to select database because: " . mysql_error());


require_once 'CSV/DataSource.php';


$filename = "users.csv";
$ext = explode(".",$filename);
$path = "uploads/".$filename;

$dbtable = $ext[0];

import_csv($dbtable, $path);


function import_csv($dbtable, $csv_file_name_with_path)
{
    $csv = new File_CSV_DataSource;
    $csv->load($csv_file_name_with_path);

    $csvData = $csv->connect();

    $res='';
    foreach($csvData  as $key)
    {
        $myKey ='';
        $myVal='';
        foreach($key as $k=>$v)
        {
            $myKey .=$k.',';
            $myVal .="'".$v."',";
          }

        $myKey = substr($myKey, 0, -1);
        $myVal = substr($myVal, 0, -1); 
        $query="insert into ".$dbtable." ($myKey)values($myVal)";
        $res=  mysql_query($query);

    }

    if($res ==1)
    {

                echo "record successfully Import.";

    }else{

                echo "record not successfully Import.";
    }
}
```